# Can one grep the whole database?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have a database with some collections. I want to find all documents from any collection that contain particular string in any of their field.

As currently I need it only for debug purposes, I can think of a solution that involves dumping everything with `mongodump` and searching those files with another tool. But this is far from perfect.

Is there a *grep whole database*-like feature in Mongo? Or at least *grep whole collection*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I really cannot think of anything efficient to do so. I really think if you believe you have this need then you are not modelling your solution properly and likely are separating items into collections when they should be in a singular collection. You might have thought there were reasons to do so for some other purpose, but clearly if you desire this type of query then that was not the best solution.

Much like your "filesystem grep" then the only real option is to iterate the entire collection and every single field. So in much the same way as done by `grep`:

```js
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(colname) {
    db.getCollection(colname).find().forEach(function(doc) {
        var json = JSON.stringify( doc );
        if ( json.match(/string/) != null )
            printjson(doc);
    });
});
```

So basically cycle through each collection and dump each document as a "JSON string" and use a regex match on the string to see if the content matches. If it does then print it out.

But seriously, rethink what you are doing here. If you think you need this kind of feature then you likely really need all the data you wish to `grep` in a single collection instead. Then you can use indexes within reason, at least as long as the "terms" match the possible beginning of a string.

Of course a ["text index"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) which you can always specify for multiple fields. You can do this like this:

```js
db.collection.ensureIndex(
    { "$**": "textIndex" },
    { "name": "TextIndex" }
)
```

That doesn't solve the "multiple-database" question as you really should not do that. But it should be preferred to transforming a document to a JSON string and using a regex on that, unless a regex is specifically required for the match.